# How to shutdown computer at "Set Up Windows" after fresh factory re-install

Tags: windows-7, factory-defaults

I have performed a factory restore of a Packard Bell laptop (Easynote TJ68 - Windows 7 x64 Home Premium) using the D2D (Disc-to-Disc) recovery through the Packard Bell Recovery Manager application pre-installed on the laptop.

I would like the new owner to be able to run through the initial "Set Up Windows" wizard (similar to picture below) where they select their language, enter a computer name and create a new user but there is no option to shut the computer down at this process.

How can I shutdown the laptop at this stage that won't cause Windows to complain at the next boot?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This should be the same steps for any laptop where the "**Set Up Windows**" wizard is displayed:

1. At the "**Set Up Windows**" wizard screen press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>
2. When the **Command Prompt** window opens type `shutdown /s /t 1` and press <kbd>Return</kbd>
3. After approximately 10-20 seconds the laptop will shutdown
4. Done!

Note: I have tested this and the next reboot I am greeted with the "**Set Up Windows**" screen.

Edit: added `/t 1` to command line to force time to shutdown from Windows default ~20 seconds to 1 second, thank to Miles Wolbe.

Comment: This answer still works for Windows 10 April 2018 Update.

Comment: You can speed up the process considerably by adding `/t 1` to the `shutdown` command (time=1 second).

Comment: Note that you may also need to press the Fn key on some computers to select F10

Comment: Works on Windows 11 too.